# Backend Service metrics in AppDynamics

Tags: appdynamics

My java application is connected to remote webservice application where appdynamics is not installed. I am seeing those services as backed services. The remote webservice application has multiple webservices. I want to track response time of each webservice separately. Should i create different tier for each service or resolve all services into single tier? Is there any other better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Business transactions should accomplish this. If you want to report on each web service you can build a report or custom dashboard. If you need more assistance just email help@appdynamics.com